# email service on websites

Tags: web-server, email-server

I tried sending an email with my gmail account and it worked:

```
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'my@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxx',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from($this->input->post('email'));
        $this->email->to('my@gmail.com'); 


        $this->email->subject('Email From user');
        $this->email->message('You have received an email from a user.');

        $result = $this->email->send();
```

However, I need to get it running on another server. Now the actual email address that the email is sent to is the actual name of the site: info@thesite.com. But when I try sending it to this email, it doesn't work. The site is hosted on rackspace cloud, but I am not sure if the email is serviced through rackspace cloud. And the guy to ask wouldn't know the answer. Is there a way to find out where the email is being serviced because I need an smtp username and password in order to send the email.

thanks for response

Comment: Can you access the mail log on the rackspace cloud, and does it say anything about why this specific message failed? I'm not an expert on email servers (and definitely not rackspace), but when I've had problems like this in the past, the error logs help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find out if there are any MX records in use/play "nslookup -type=mx (thesite.com - identifying the real site would have helped)" (without the quotes and replace the () text with the actual domain).
2. traceroute or tracert (depending on the rest of the world or Windows) to the MX identified server(s) or the domain, if MX records are not in use

The last entry/entries of the trace will typically provide good hints as to where/with whom the servers are located.

Comment: Thanks for response. I did a nslookup as you suggested. No while the site is hosted wiht rackspace cloud, I know they use deltacom for some kind of other service. So when nslookup gave me back a mail server, I googled it and it says the ip is deltacom, which is a totally different server: http://bgp.he.net/ip/97.66.39.82#_whois So now I am confused as to whether the email is serviced through rackspace or deltacom

Comment: Some ISPs do "outsource" email and other services to other service providers (e.g. AT&T had Yahoo! run their user services like email, not sure if that is still the case though). You might check through their respective sites for additional clues or contact them directly for the authoritative answer.